# MVUE is unique - wrong proof?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, estimation, inference, point-estimation

Here is the proof of "MVUE is unique" that my lecturer gave:
[image: first_part]
[image: second_part]

Now I understand the following:

- The first expansion is done using the formula for the sum of correlated random variables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables).
- I understand that, having arrived at the result $Var(T+\lambda(T'-T)) = Var(T) - \frac{\rho^2}{\gamma}$ we require $\rho=0$ because otherwise $Var(T) - \frac{\rho^2}{\gamma} < Var(T)$ which is not possible, since $T$ is MVUE.

However, it seems to me that the lecturer made a mistake in the statement just after this. Indeed, if we require $\rho=0$ then surely $\lambda:=\frac{\rho}{\gamma} = \frac{0}{\gamma}=0$ right?

And, consequently, we don't have $Var(T+\lambda(T'-T)) = Var(T)+\lambda^2 Var(T'-T)$ but rather $Var(T+0(T'-T))= Var(T)$ which is just an identity obviously.

What's more is that we cannot choose $\lambda$ to be $1$ because clearly, it turned out to be $0$.

Am I reading the proof correctly?

Comment: Much hinges on the quantifiers "specifically" and "for all $\lambda$."

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.. The lecturer chose a very specific $\lambda=\frac{\rho}{\gamma}$ to prove that $\rho=0$. Therefore now he cannot use a different $\lambda$ because otherwise we wouldn't know if $\rho=0$ or not.

Comment: Here's another way to see it: after the phrase "which results in," replace all occurrences of "$\lambda$" by some other letter, such as $\nu.$

Comment: Please do not [cross post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2955396/321264).

Comment: There is a typo in the final displayed equation which is that "=0" should not be there. The argument is that$$\text{var}T=\text{var}T'+\lambda^2\text{var}(T-T')=\text{var}T'$$implies that$$\text{var}(T-T')=0$$hence that$$T\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{=}T$$

Comment: @Xi'an thank you! What does a.s. mean on top of the equal sign?

Comment: a.s. stands for almost surely in standard probability theory

Comment: Oh right, so they are the same except in a countable number of pointwise realizations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lecturer intends for $\lambda$ to be a free variable in the variance equation.  He initially uses a specific value $\lambda=\rho/\gamma$
 to show that $\rho=0$.  Having done this, he reverts to the general form of the variance equation and shows the rest of the proof using the new specific value $\lambda=1$.  Perhaps he could have been a bit clearer about this in his proof.  Here is a clearer version of the same proof.

> **Result:** The MVUE is (almost surely) unique.
>
> **Proof:** Suppose that $T$ and $T'$ are both MVUE for $g(\theta)$.  If $\mathbb{V}(T'-T)=0$ then $T' \overset{\text{a.s}}{=} T$ which completes the proof.  We now proceed for the non-trivial case where $\mathbb{V}(T'-T)>0$.
>
> For any scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ the estimator $T + \lambda (T'-T)$ is an unbiased estimator with variance:
>   $$\mathbb{V}(T + \lambda (T'-T)) = \mathbb{V}(T) + \lambda^2 \mathbb{V}(T'-T) + 2 \lambda \mathbb{C}(T,T'-T).$$
>   Now, using a specific value of our scalar we have:
>   $$\lambda = - \frac{\mathbb{C}(T,T'-T)}{\mathbb{V}(T'-T)} \quad \quad \implies \quad \quad \mathbb{V}(T + \lambda (T'-T)) = \mathbb{V}(T) - \frac{\mathbb{C}(T,T'-T)^2}{\mathbb{V}(T'-T)}.$$
>   Since $T + \lambda (T'-T)$ is an unbiased estimator, it cannot have a variance lower than $\mathbb{V}(T)$ (since $T$ is MVUE).  This means that $\mathbb{C}(T,T'-T)=0$ (i.e., $T$ and $T'-T$ are uncorrelated), which allows us to simplify the variance equation down to:
>   $$\mathbb{V}(T + \lambda (T'-T)) = \mathbb{V}(T) + \lambda^2 \mathbb{V}(T'-T).$$
>   Using a new value for our scalar we then obtain:
>   $$\lambda = 1 \quad \quad \implies \quad \quad \mathbb{V}(T') = \mathbb{V}(T) + \mathbb{V}(T'-T).$$
>   Since $T'$ and $T$ are both MVUE, they must have the same variance as each other, and so we must have $\mathbb{V}(T'-T)=0$.  This gives $T' \overset{\text{a.s}}{=} T$, which completes the proof. $\text{ } \blacksquare$